# Linking to a external Url - currently unsuccessful

Tags: html, hyperlink

When I try link a ext Url such as `www.facebook.com` it currently comes as -

```
mysite.com/music/www.facebook.com
```

Its linked: `<a href="www.facebook.com></a>` as i link internal urls like `<a href=./index.html>` etc etc

How to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're talking about in HTML.  You need the full URL, e.g. `http://www.example.com`, not just `www.example.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an `http://` prefix to your URLs: `http://stackoverflow.com/faq`

You might find the [HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html) interesting reading. (Probably not. But pay attention to the `12.4.1 Relative URIs` section at the bottom of the page. :)